# Swashbuckle-Swagger documentation for routes made via Config.MapRoute during startup?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

During startup of my .NET Core 2.0 web API, I register routes to my controllers via the `MapRoute()` method.  I would like swagger to recognize these routes or allow me to add them during startup.  I know the documentation indicates swagger does not support conventional routing out of the box (only attribute based routing), but does anyone have any alternatives to providing documentation for routes created dynamically during startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConventionalRouting](https://github.com/chsakell/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConventionalRouting) which replaces the original Swagger generator with a custom one that recognizes conventional routes. It supports ASP.NET Core 2.1 and ASP.NET Core 3.X applications. I have used it in a production application with more than 400 dynamic conventional routes (custom constraints, regexes, etc) and the results are pretty good.